# How to add language tags like "<html lang=es>" in just some certain pages?

Tags: multi-language, language

How is it possible to add the language-tag like  at a certain wordpress page? Background: I have some translated articles in my blog and want add to add this tag to the sites I translated. How is it possible? I did not find any plugin therefore and as a coding noob and dont have any idea how to handle this issue.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you use a i8n plugin such as WPML?

Comment: No I dont think so. But I am a totally coding noob. Could I solve the problem with WPML?

Comment: WPML is a full-on solution for translating websites / parts of websites. I wouldn't recommend it if there's only a few articles being translated. Now, how to answer your question really depends on how you're handling translations. Do you simply have the posts listed under "Posts" in several languages? How many of them are there?